# Не работает Raycast. Не реагирует

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите пожалуйста. Луч не реагирует не на какие колайдеры. Rg никак не влияет. Думал проблема в том, что он изначально в колайдере, но когда он за его пределами все также

```
if (Physics.Raycast(new Ray(transform.position, outerObj.transform.position), out RaycastHit hit, 4f, 10, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide))
                        Debug.LogWarning("LOL");
```

[image: но]

Comment: Может проблема в том, что он дочерний? Если да то как это можно исправить

Comment: `Raycast` работает! С помощью `Debug.DrawRay` ради прикола нарисуй луч этого рейкаста... увидишь свою проблему. Нет, там не будет ошибки, он такой каким ты его сделал.

Comment: Так я и дебажу его, на картинке результат дебага. Но проблема не решилась

Comment: Боюсь выглядеть капитаном очевидностью, но `LogWarning` это не `DrawRay`, он не покажет тебе куда луч направлен.

Comment: Я рисую рей с помощью Debag.Ray(), капитан очевидность, а логварнинг я вывожу после проверки вне зависимости от результата

Comment: Может я и капитан, но не ванга, ни в коде, ни на скрине луча не видно. Два лоуполе маникена в Т-позах и сфера колайдера, хендлер торчит в бошке одного из них... все.

Comment: Понимаю, можешь не разглядывать картинку, на которой есть линия пересекающая триггер. Поверь тогда на слово, он пересекает колайдер